# ios - locationManager returning 0.0000

Tags: ios, objective-c, cllocationmanager

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
     NSURLSessionConfiguration *config = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
     config.URLCache = [[NSURLCache alloc] initWithMemoryCapacity:2 * 1024 * 1024
                                                    diskCapacity:10 * 1024 * 1024
                                                        diskPath:@"MarkerData"];
    self.markerSession = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:config];


    locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    NSLog(@"locationServicesEnabled: %@", [CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled] ? @"YES":@"NO");

    CLLocationManager *lm = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    lm.delegate = self;
    lm.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
    lm.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
    [lm startUpdatingLocation];
    //[lm stopUpdatingLocation];

    CLLocation *location = [lm location];

    CLLocationCoordinate2D coord;
    coord.longitude = location.coordinate.longitude;
    NSString *ss= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f",coord.longitude ];

    coord.latitude = location.coordinate.latitude;
    NSString *aa= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f",coord.latitude ];
    NSLog(@"oooooooo2");
    NSLog(ss);
    NSLog(aa);
    NSLog(@"kkkkkkkkk2");

}
```

Answer (score 2):

`CLLocationManager` is asynchronous. By the time the code at the bottom executes, it will not have and a chance to get a location. You should implement methods from `CLLocationManagerDelegate` such as `–locationManager:didUpdateLocations:`:

```
@interface MyClass() <CLLocationManagerDelegate>

@end

@implementation MyClass

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    ...
    CLLocationManager *lm = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    lm.delegate = self;
    ...
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)locationManager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
{
    CLLocation *location = [locationManager location];
    CLLocationCoordinate2D coord;
    coord.longitude = location.coordinate.longitude;
    etc...
}

@end
```

Someone has also made a [block-based version](https://github.com/axldyb/CLLocationManager-blocks), if you’re into that sort of thing.